# Can't Post a long text to my php

Tags: php

This is my `promotion.php`

```
<form action="postingPromotionUpdate.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Promo Title: <input type="text" name="promotionTitle"/><br/>
Promo Remark: <textarea name="promotionText" cols="100" rows="10" </textarea><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Update"/>
</form>
```

This is my `postPromotion.php`

```
    include 'connect.php';
    $promotionTitle=$_POST['promotionTitle'];
    $promotionText=$_POST['promotionText'];
mysql_query("update promotion set promotionTitle = '$promotionTitle', promotionText = '$promotionText' where indexNum = 1");
    echo "<script>alert('Update Successful!');</script>";
```

If I post short text, no problem. When I post a very long text, can't to post and save it.

Comment: if you are not able to fetch data on `postPromotion.php`. then check your `php.ini` for `post_max_size`

Comment: check the column's length.

Comment: You also need to remove / replace single quotes ' in fields before sending it to SQL.

Comment: @PeterK are you talking about this? `promotionTitle = '$promotionTitle', promotionText = '$promotionText'` to remove the quotes? If so, nope. That is false information you're giving. Those are string literals.

Comment: This is also not being closed <textarea name="promotionText" cols="100" rows="10"

Comment: @WesMurray ah, good catch. If that's their *real* code ;-)

Comment: What does "can't to post and save it" mean?  How *specifically* does it fail?

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Look at what @Fred-ii- said [in the second comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36036611/cant-post-a-long-text-to-my-php#comment59722232_36036611). Your column width is too small. *Bulls-eye Ralph!*

Comment: I think they've mostly turned a ***blind** eye* to it there Sam - @JayBlanchard who knows. could be a mix of 2-3 things. Let them see the answer below. I am off to the *Running of the bulls*. - ciao for now mi amico.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I was talking about sanitizing input against SQL injection, but I see my approach was outdated long ago )

Comment: @PeterK I might also have misinterpreted your comment. In a way, if the OP is introducing any character that MySQL may be complaining about, then that would have shown up in `mysql_error()`, something they're not using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe That's because  of two reasons
1.Your character type in mysql maybe short (like varchar[100]) use 'longtext' as character type
2.you don't use mysql_real_escape_string.If single quotes comes in your text query breakes.
Use this function to recover that.

```
function clean($str)
{
$str = @trim($str);
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {$str = stripslashes($str);  }
return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}
$promotionTitle=clean($_POST['promotionTitle']);
$promotionText=clean($_POST['promotionText']);
```

Comment: No, no, no, no, no! Please do not recommend old, deprecated technologies. The OP should learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: He asked about his code so i just told him,anyway thanks

Comment: I think using PDO is better than mysqli,maybe in future mysqli also deprecate